# Error when building OpenCV 3 for Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I am trying to build OpenCV 3 for Mac OS X.  I am following the instructions from http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/

I get the following output:

```
...
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_latentsvm
[ 50%] Built target opencv_test_latentsvm
[ 50%] Building CXX object modules/features2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_features2d.dir/perf/perf_main.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object modules/line_descriptor/CMakeFiles/opencv_line_descriptor.dir/src/binary_descriptor_matcher.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object modules/features2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_features2d.dir/test/test_keypoints.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object modules/features2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_features2d.dir/perf/perf_orb.cpp.o
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_saliency
[ 50%] Building CXX object modules/saliency/CMakeFiles/opencv_saliency.dir/src/BING/CmFile.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object modules/line_descriptor/CMakeFiles/opencv_line_descriptor.dir/src/draw.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object modules/features2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_features2d.dir/test/test_main.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object modules/saliency/CMakeFiles/opencv_saliency.dir/src/BING/CmShow.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object modules/line_descriptor/CMakeFiles/opencv_line_descriptor.dir/src/LSDDetector.cpp.o
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_perf_features2d
[ 50%] Built target opencv_perf_features2d
[ 50%] Building CXX object modules/features2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_features2d.dir/test/test_matchers_algorithmic.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object modules/saliency/CMakeFiles/opencv_saliency.dir/src/BING/FilterTIG.cpp.o
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_text
[ 50%] Building CXX object modules/text/CMakeFiles/opencv_text.dir/src/erfilter.cpp.o
/Users/samadwara/opencv_contrib/modules/line_descriptor/src/LSDDetector.cpp:182:37: error: call to 'pow' is ambiguous
      kl.lineLength = (float) sqrt( pow( extremes[0] - extremes[2], 2 ) + pow( extremes[1] - extremes[3], 2 ) );
                                    ^~~
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cmath:364:3: note: candidate function
  pow(double __x, int __i)
  ^
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cmath:368:3: note: candidate function
  pow(float __x, int __n)
  ^
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cmath:372:3: note: candidate function
  pow(long double __x, int __n)
  ^
/usr/include/math.h:436:15: note: candidate function
extern double pow(double, double);
              ^
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cmath:356:3: note: candidate function
  pow(float __x, float __y)
  ^
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cmath:360:3: note: candidate function
  pow(long double __x, long double __y)
  ^
/Users/samadwara/opencv_contrib/modules/line_descriptor/src/LSDDetector.cpp:182:75: error: call to 'pow' is ambiguous
      kl.lineLength = (float) sqrt( pow( extremes[0] - extremes[2], 2 ) + pow( extremes[1] - extremes[3], 2 ) );
                                                                          ^~~
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cmath:364:3: note: candidate function
  pow(double __x, int __i)
  ^
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cmath:368:3: note: candidate function
  pow(float __x, int __n)
  ^
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cmath:372:3: note: candidate function
  pow(long double __x, int __n)
  ^
/usr/include/math.h:436:15: note: candidate function
extern double pow(double, double);
              ^
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cmath:356:3: note: candidate function
  pow(float __x, float __y)
  ^
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cmath:360:3: note: candidate function
  pow(long double __x, long double __y)
  ^
2 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [modules/line_descriptor/CMakeFiles/opencv_line_descriptor.dir/src/LSDDetector.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/line_descriptor/CMakeFiles/opencv_line_descriptor.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 50%] Building CXX object modules/features2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_features2d.dir/test/test_mser.cpp.o
[ 51%] Building CXX object modules/saliency/CMakeFiles/opencv_saliency.dir/src/BING/objectnessBING.cpp.o
[ 51%] Building CXX object modules/text/CMakeFiles/opencv_text.dir/src/ocr_hmm_decoder.cpp.o
[ 51%] Building CXX object modules/features2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_features2d.dir/test/test_nearestneighbors.cpp.o
[ 51%] Building CXX object modules/saliency/CMakeFiles/opencv_saliency.dir/src/BING/ValStructVec.cpp.o
[ 51%] Building CXX object modules/saliency/CMakeFiles/opencv_saliency.dir/src/motionSaliency.cpp.o
[ 51%] Building CXX object modules/text/CMakeFiles/opencv_text.dir/src/ocr_tesseract.cpp.o
[ 51%] Building CXX object modules/features2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_features2d.dir/test/test_orb.cpp.o
[ 51%] Building CXX object modules/saliency/CMakeFiles/opencv_saliency.dir/src/motionSaliencyBinWangApr2014.cpp.o
[ 51%] Building CXX object modules/saliency/CMakeFiles/opencv_saliency.dir/src/objectness.cpp.o
[ 51%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_text.dylib
[ 51%] Built target opencv_text
[ 51%] Building CXX object modules/features2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_features2d.dir/test/test_rotation_and_scale_invariance.cpp.o
[ 51%] Building CXX object modules/saliency/CMakeFiles/opencv_saliency.dir/src/saliency.cpp.o
[ 51%] Building CXX object modules/saliency/CMakeFiles/opencv_saliency.dir/src/staticSaliency.cpp.o
[ 51%] Building CXX object modules/saliency/CMakeFiles/opencv_saliency.dir/src/staticSaliencySpectralResidual.cpp.o
[ 51%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_saliency.dylib
[ 51%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_features2d
[ 51%] Built target opencv_saliency
[ 51%] Built target opencv_test_features2d
make: *** [all] Error 2
 ~/opencv/build $
```

Any ideas about how to resolve this issue?  If all else fails, I'll just install a Linux VM and use that.

Comment: You should report this to the OpenCV 3 developers, and check if your compiler is supported. From your error message `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1` i surmise you are using something like gcc version 4.2.1? That is extremely old, you might want to upgrade.

Comment: How would I go about updating it?  I downloaded gcc 5.2.0 and replaced /usr/bin/gcc (this may have been a bad idea), yet it still tries to use /usr/include/c++/4.2.1.

Comment: I don't know how you downloaded it... probably you should build it from source using homebrew or something for best results. And you need to make sure that when you build OpenCV that you tell it to use the newer version

Comment: I downloaded it using brew, and then copied the file from my homebrew directory to /usr/bin/gcc.  How do I tell OpenCV which to use?

Comment: (1) don't copy things away from brew, just use them wherever brew puts them (2) read some documentation on cmake so you can learn how to use the build system and tell it what compiler to use

Comment: have you tried to disable IPP after generating the make files, i had a lot of problems related to IPP, it may be yours too.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue going through this process. For some reason that version of cmath does not include methods for handling integer, integer arguments for the power function (extremes is a vector of integers at that part of the code). I added a new function to handle it, the code for which I have included below. A few other issues will be raised if the compilation continues when power is applied to integer, float or integer, double arguments. For these you can just use the existing built-in methods for the power function.

After making the adjustment to cmath and continuing with the installation, I ran into no further issues.

C++ code for power(integer, integer) adapted from the Exponentiation by Squaring article on wikipedia:

```
inline double 
pow(int __x, int __n)
{
    double myx = __x, myn = __n;
    if (__n<0){
        myx = 1.0/ __x;
        myn = -__n;
    } 
    if(__n==0){
        return 1; 
    }
    double myy=1;
    while(myn > 1){
       if (((int)myn)%2==0){
           myx = myx * myx;
           myn = myn / 2;
       }else{
           myy = myx * myy;
           myx = myx * myx;
           myn = (myn - 1) / 2;
       }
    }
    return myx*myy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for shapiromh. Due to your solution, I can solve this problem. To do so, I modified the cmath source as below as like your case.

```
  inline double
  pow(int __x, int __y)
  { return __builtin_powf(__x, __y); }
```